# Least Non-Square Quadratic Residue

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

There's a lot of work on the least quadratic non-residues for a given modulus p (usually prime), with research on bounds and distributions providing some interesting [results](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/the-least-quadratic-nonresidue-and-the-square-root-barrier/).

The justification for focusing on non-residues is typically that the least residue is trivial since 1 is a square for all integer moduli. Of course, all square numbers are trivially quadratic residues for all moduli. But what about the smallest non-trivial quadratic residue? That is, the smallest non-square quadratic residue?

Denote $ \theta (n) $ the least non-square quadratic residue for modulus $n$, where $ \theta (n) = 0 $ if there is not a non-square quadratic residue . The chart below shows the value of $\theta (n) $ for $2 \leq n \leq 1000$.

[image]

One observation I have made is that local maxima of this function often occur when $n$ is a highly smooth number (factorisation contains small primes), and the corresponding value $\theta(n)$ is also often 1 larger than a smooth number (but not always).

For example, the sequential maxima (red dots) for the chart above are:

$$
\theta(6 = 2 \cdot 3) = 3 = 1 + 2 \\
\theta(9 = 3^2 ) = 7 = 1 + 2 \cdot 3 \\
\theta(24 = 2^3 \cdot 3) = 12 = 1 + 11 \\
\theta(32 = 2^5) = 17 = 1 + 2^4 \\
\theta(40 = 2^3 \cdot 5) = 20 = 1 + 19 \\
\theta(48 = 2^4 \cdot 3) = 33 = 1 + 2^5 \\
\theta(144 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2) = 52 = 1 + 3 \cdot 17 \\
\theta(240 = 2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5) = 84 = 1 + 83 \\
\theta(480 = 2^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 5) = 96 = 1 + 5 \cdot 19 \\ 
\theta(720 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 ) = 145 = 1 + 2^4 \cdot 3^2 $$

Furthermore, for $ n \leq 100000$ the maximum value of $\theta (n)$ is obtained when $n = 50400, \theta(n) = 721 $, with $ 50400 = 2^5 \times 3^2 \times 5^2 \times 7 $ and  $ 721 = 1 + 2^4 \times 3^2 \times 5$

I guess my question is whether anyone knows of any existing research on this kind of function? Any recommendations welcome! Thanks.

Comment: I feel the definition still needs some clarification, otherwise you seem to be saying that 2 is a quadratic residue modulo 3.

Comment: Yes, that would be quite a discovery. Let me check.

Comment: Edited. I made an error when porting my code to python that used n-1 as a dumb placeholder when there was no non-square residue. Of course mod 3 is one such case, a long with a few other low numbers. Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at [Polya-Vinogradov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#The_P.C3.B3lya.E2.80.93Vinogradov_inequality) ?